# rewire ventilation fan to use pull chain instead of wall switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, exhaust-fan

I'm converting part of an unfinished space to make a darkroom. I'm installing a bathroom ventilation fan over the sink but there is no convenient place to install a switch for the fan. I purchased a pull-chain switch and would like to install this in the ceiling next to the fan, as a pull-chain dangling above the sink would be a far more convenient way to turn the fan on and off. I'm just not sure if this will be safe electrically. Are there any issues I need to consider?

Answer (score 1):

The switch must be in a listed and labeled enclosure, or the switch itself must have a built-in enclosure. The switch should also be rated for the voltage, and current, to which it will be subjected.

You'll also want to make sure the switch is attached in such a way, that normal use will not rip it from the enclosure. Pull chains can be subjected to a lot of abuse.

Comment: In other words attach to the joist not just the drywall.